# XSL generated a security exception

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, suo

Here's the background.  I'm using VS 2015 to do XSLT debugging and my XSLT used the document function to pull in a document.   Doing so generated a 'XSL generated a security exception.' error.

I get that, but now I'm just doing a simple transform and VS throws the same error.  I'm not doing anything fancy.

I've tried restarting VS, but no luck.  I think I had this problem in the past and I had to delete a temp file that VS created somewhere to fix it, but I can't remember.  SUO file or something?

Comment: I found the .suo file and deleted it, but I still get the bug.  "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".  I'm not using the document function so it shouldn't be connecting to anything.

Comment: This is not a security exception. This just says that the machine you are trying to connect to is not listening on the port you are trying to use.

Comment: But I'm not connecting to a machine.  I'm using the VS 2015 "start xslt debugging" command on the XML menu

Comment: OK, not an answer, but I figured a workaround.  I put the cursor in the xml file and then ran 'start xslt debugging' and it worked.  No error.  If I put the cursor in the xslt file, however, it still bombs.  Also, to fix the underlying document function security issue I had to copy the xml to the local folder.  This stinks of course, because that solution won't work in PROD where I don't have complete control of the location of xml files, even those in my own domain.